# Passing a variable from new form to event handler

Tags: c#, variables, event-handling, initialization

I want to be able to access my new variable (index) created from another variable(target). I've successfully passed it though from one form to the new form. The target variable was chosen by the user choosing a name from a list and then clicking a button.

```
    public UpdateStudentScores(int target)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int index = target;
    }

    private List<Student> students;

    private void UpdateStudentScores_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtName.Text = students[index].WholeName;
    }
```

I will be using the new variable(index) as my index to populate the text boxes in the new form. I'm not familiar with the event that contains my InitializeComponent(); so I'm not sure how to get that variable out. Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the variable `index` outside of the constructor. Then you can set the value of that variable from the constructor and can be used anywhere in that form.

```
int index=0;
public UpdateStudentScores(int target)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.index = target;
}

private List<Student> students;

private void UpdateStudentScores_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    txtName.Text = students[index].WholeName;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark answered please, thkx @RagingBull.

Answer (score 1):

You can place `index` variable outside of the constructor. Make it field or property.

```
int index;
public UpdateStudentScores(int target)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    index = target
}

private List<Student> students;

private void UpdateStudentScores_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    txtName.Text = students[index].WholeName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable 'Index' globally and you'll be able to access it.